# Visual Studio 2017 does not handle properly SQLite DB

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, rider

I used JetBrains Rider to create an SQLite database (14 tables and 6 views). Rider was more user friendly than Visual Studio 2017. I went back to Visual Studio for the c# programing part. The "SQLite-SQL Server Compact Toolbox" was able to connect to the DB but there were some error messages. For example when I wanted to "Edit top 200 rows" of a table there was an error but the select * worked. More importantly, when I wanted to add ADO object (to use Entity framework) there was an error again.

When I created some tables in VS there was no such problem. So I wonder where can be the problem?

Comment: Don't have an answer but wondering what made you go back to Visual Studio for the C# programming part if Rider lets you do that part first and foremost?

Comment: Further symptom: There is a suspected view. I dropped the view. The view disappeared from "SQLite-SQL Server Compact Toolbox". If I try to edit a table with the toolbox, it misses the dropped view. There should be no connection with that view. The latest toolbox version is installed with VS2017. Rider has no such problem.

Comment: I am the author of the "SQLite Toolbox" - I suggest you post an issue here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/issues with a repro database, then we can work together to solve the issue

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ I figured out the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem is with "SQLite-SQL Server Compact Toolbox". If the definition of the Views has comments then you can not add entity framework based on your database using Visual Studio. Though the database is ok, the select * from myTable works.
Rider has no problem with comments in View.
The toolbox has no problem with comment in table just in the view.